# Implementing FFMpeg -r and -vf like feature using libav* libraries?

Tags: ffmpeg, mjpeg, libavcodec, libavformat, vaapi

Wondering if anyone can offer some pointers on how use FFMpeg libav* libraries to implement the following? Specially the -r and -vf options?

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD129 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i my.mp4  -vf 'scale_vaapi=w=640:h=480' -r 1/10 -c:v mjpeg_vaapi -global_quality 90 -f image2 my_%03d.jpeg
```